# How to send latest csv as attachment in email within a folder

Tags: csv, powershell, attachment

I am trying to write a script which looks in a folder for latest file and email it to a user, after running the below script I am not getting any errors but I am not receiving any email. Not sure how to check for latest file in a folder.

```
$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$message = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$message.Recipients.Add("test@test.com")  #obviously this is not the right   email
$message.Subject = "test"  
$message.Body = "this is test email"


$file = "P:\test\test.csv"
$message.Attachments.Add($file)
```

Hi I have tried searching on internet and put together a script to list the latest file now i just need to attach the file and send over the email

```
$dir = "P:\Source\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending   
| Select-Object -First 1
$newfile = $latest.name



$FilePath = Join-Path $dir $newfile
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True)

{email bit should come here}
```

Not sure how to put the send message (i am new to powershell)

Comment: Which problem are we to try and fix. No sense working on attaching files when you are not receiving the mail.

Comment: You'll need to at least call `$message.Send()` if you want to send it

Answer (score 0):

All i got this working as below

```
$dir = "p:\test\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending 
| Select-Object -First 1
$newfile = $latest.name



$FilePath = Join-Path $dir $newfile
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$message = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$message.Recipients.Add("test@test.com")  #obviously this is not the right    
email
$message.Subject = "test"  
$message.Body = "this is test email"


$file = $FilePath
$message.Attachments.Add($file)
$message.Send()
Write-Host "File is emailed "
}
else
{write-host "No File Found"}
```